# Loading in a custom Typescript class through dojo not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, dojo, requirejs, arcgis-js-api

I've got a custom class that I'd like to kick off, using the Dojo loader. I seem close, but there seems to be an issue with what gets injected.

My dojoConfig points to the correct script, this works fine. If the typescript file includes JUST statements, it works, it fires off anything it contains.

```
var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        { name: "Viewer", location: "/scripts", main: "Viewer" }
    ],
    parseOnLoad: false
};
```

This is the code where I bring in the custom class. While I said it works fine if the typescript is just statements, when the typescript is a class, the line where I call the constructor doesn't error, but it also doesn't work. When I set a break point and inspect the viewer variable, it has a few arcgis related properties in it, so that leads me to believe there is something going wrong with the injection.

I require it to be constructed because I need to pass variables in on start up. Otherwise this really wouldn't be an issue.

```
        require([
            "esri/map",
            "esri/dijit/ElevationProfile",
            ...
            "dojo/domReady!",
            "Viewer"
        ], function(Map, ElevationsProfileWidget, Viewer) {
            Loader(Map, ElevationsProfileWidget, Viewer);
        });

        function Loader(Map, ElevationsProfileWidget, Viewer) {
            ...
            var viewer = new Viewer(false, false);
        }
```

This is the typescript class for context...

```
import TopNavToolbar = require("./TopNavToolbar");
import IdentifyTool = require("./IdentifyTool");

class Viewer
{
    topToolbar: TopNavToolbar;

    constructor(public AddMeasure: boolean, public AddIdentify: boolean) {

        console.log("constructed");
    }
}
export = Viewer;
```

And this is the JS it creates, if it necessary

```
define(["require", "exports", "./TopNavToolbar", "./IdentifyTool"], function (require, exports, TopNavToolbar, IdentifyTool) {
    "use strict";
    var Viewer = (function () {
        function Viewer(AddMeasure, AddIdentify) {
            this.AddMeasure = AddMeasure;
            this.AddIdentify = AddIdentify;
            this.topToolbar = new TopNavToolbar('ulToolbar');
            console.log("constructed");
        }
        return Viewer;
    }());
    return Viewer;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=Viewer.js.map
```

Comment: So you are using the old dojo? The dojo before RequireJS shone its great light upon us (I am being dead serious RequireJS is awesome)? If so, that means, IIRC, that instead of define, you need to use `dojo.declare` to register you class. Since TypeScript does not support transpiling to the framework specific dojo format, you will need to write the class declaration manually. You may need a few stub type declarations but it won't be hard.

Comment: Which version of dojo are you using? Some dijits require outdated stuff, at least when I last used them, to declare classes for things like map popups

Comment: Look in the debugger, right before you invoke `new Viewier` and examine `Viewer` and `Viewer.prototype`. If you don't have what you expect, and if statements work correctly, the loader may be trying to shim your module or something weird like that.

Comment: Thanks Aluan, it ended up being the order of the require strings. I was unaware that mattered, but it makes total sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being something hilariously small. I was unaware that the require strings need to be in the same order as the function parameters that bring them in. So in this example, domReady would be binded to Viewer. Once I moved the Viewer require right under the ElevationProfileWidget, everything worked as expected

```
require([
            "esri/map",
            "esri/dijit/ElevationProfile",
            "Viewer",
            "dojo/domReady!" 
        ], function(Map, ElevationsProfileWidget, Viewer) {
            Loader(Map, ElevationsProfileWidget, Viewer);
        });

        function Loader(Map, ElevationsProfileWidget, Viewer) {
            ...
            var viewer = new Viewer(false, false);
        }
```

Comment: I totally missed this error when reading your question. My eyes just skipped right over the bootstrapping code, assuming it was written correctly since I've seen it so many times. Glad you got it working.